# Display image with https url

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-phone-8.1, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I need to display image into app. I am using below code for the same.

```
<Ellipse Height="60" Width="60" >
  <Ellipse.Fill>
     <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
  </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Here *ImageUrl* is string url.

My issue is if url starts with ***https://*** and server used **self signed certificate**, I am not able to see image rendered, with ***http://*** it works fine.

**Note**: Its not HttpClient so can't apply filter here.

Any suggestion to override ssl in this case?
Thanks

**UPDATE 1:**
I have added certificate into app using this code:

```
System.Uri certificateFile = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/temp.cer");
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(certificateFile);
Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer certBlob = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);

// Create an instance of the Certificate class using the retrieved certificate blob contents
Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate rootCert = new Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate(certBlob);

// Get access to the TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities for your own app (not the system one)
Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStore trustedStore = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStores.TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities;

// Add the certificate to the TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities store for your app
trustedStore.Add(rootCert);
```

Although certificate is added as I debugged, but I am not able to access https:// url. I have set build action to "Content"
Thanks

Comment: It should work, only known cases where it doesn't is if you have Fiddler running.. If you install the self-signed cert in your local trusted certs does it work?

Comment: If I install on device it will work, but is there any way to skip ssl ie allow untrusted sources?

Comment: Sorry to say, I think there is no way of adding a certificate to this request. My suggestion is, that you download the picture (using WebClient with BaseProtocolFilter) and then use the binary data as image source. Would this option work out for you?

Comment: No. I just want to display image, till image loads I am having placeholders. Downloading image(as BitmapImage/WritableBitmap) is very bad idea if there are too many images!